# Can ARCore recognise documents as well?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

ARCore can determine images and perform some action when the image is recognized.
But if I want to recognize a formal document, can ARCore be useful. So there are two parts of question :

1.) Can ARcore recognize a document (say Telephone bill). ?

2.) Can we add some actions on different parts of the document. Like showing '**Pay Bill**' button near bill amount or show a graph near data usage ?

Comment: No. You can use OpenCV for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today no. ARCore was created focusing in Object 3D rendering in a real world.

What you can do is use another "tool" like OpenCV to read and recognised the "bill" and with ARCore you could set a anchor close to where you read the bill with a chart contain some information and maybe a button.

But even, hit a Object 3D in the air is not trivial.

Maybe you should try to understand why this would e useful? 
Why not just read the bill and open informations in the app without ARCore.

ARCore has a heavy memory use, restricts devices and in this case the anchor/chart would be connect with the place, so if you move the bill (today) the chart would not follow.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/concepts) you can have more information about the uses for ARCore